# What the encryption mechanism used for CouchBase, Is it different from CouchDB?

Tags: security, encryption, couchdb, couchbase

Is there a difference between the encryption mechanisms used between Couchbase & CouchDB? Further does Couchbase provide enhanced security features than the CouchDB?

Comment: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/security/security-data-encryption.html

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase is a commercially supported Enterprise grade product. 
Following documentation explains all encryption/security features in Couchbase. RBAC for applications/users is coming in our next release (you can try them in a developer build in Feb/Mar). We also have partners to complement additional security functionality.

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/security/security-intro.html